# Route постоянно отправляет на страницу 404

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация, auth, router, error404

Здравствуйте формучане!
Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить постоянный **redirect** на страницу **404**, при этом в **/routes/web.php** маршруты на страницы верны и они существуют

**Код маршрута:**

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {
    Route::view('index', 'dashboard.index')->name('index');
});
```

Даже после авторизаций пользователя отправляет на страницу **404**

**Код маршрута:**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('dashboard');
```

Я еще заметил, что при нажатий на любую ссылку на моем сайте ответ от **Route** один ошибка 404.
Почему-то идет перенаправления на **home.blade.php** которого у меня вообще нет?

http://dawns.ddns.net/home

Comment: Покажите все свои роуты. `dashboard/index` прекрасно работает...

Comment: Он всего один, есть еще такой `Route::view('dashboard-02', 'dashboard.dashboard-02')->name('dashboard-02');` но я им не пользуюсь. Можно было бы загружать файлы я бы загрузил весь `web.php`